# Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'xxx'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view, insert

I am encountering this error when I try to `INSERT` into a table with data I pull from a view.

I have noticed many existing questions on this error are related to do with `ON` or `AND` conditions on the query, but I do not have any of these. It is a simple `SELECT x FROM ...` view which I am calling, like so...

`@query_statement = CONCAT('insert into target_table SELECT`

`mv.col1`

`mv.col2`

`mv.col3`

`FROM (',database_name,'.myView mv) );`

You will notice that I am using a variable database_name as this statement sits within a stored procedure and loops through a bunch of databases, calling a view attached to each and then inserting this data into a separate table. (I understand this is not a very good approach but this is a legacy issue we inherited)

Now the main error I face which makes this a nightmare to debug is that this query works on some databases, but not others. I have checked the source table which the view is being called upon and there are no columns which have DOUBLE as a datatype.

Comment: There's a datatype conversion going on; must be some of the `target_table` columns are defined as numeric (DECIMAL or integer type), and it must be that one of the `myView` tables/views is returning a value that needs to be converted, because one of the columns being returned (col1, col2 or col3) is a different type than the target column. MySQL converts to DOUBLE as an intermediate step. The reported value of `'xxx'` means that one of the returned expressions is character type.  (Was there a question here?)

Comment: @spencer7593 I have double and triple checked all the column types between the source and the target tables. There can only one column which is returning the error and the column type for both is VARCHAR(255). Could you explain further about MYSQL converting to a DOUBLE as an intermediate step? For sure there is no column in either table with a DOUBLE data type so perhaps this is happening at some point during the INSERT. I have also tried to CAST and CONVERT explicitly the offending column and the same error remains.

Comment: datatype conversion is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html ... mostly guessing here, but appears to be a character string being converted to numeric i.e. MySQL execution plan is converting a character string to a floating point value (DOUBLE), and the floating point value is being supplied to the insert for a numeric column. (i.e. we wouldn't expect this error if the target column was character type)

Comment: We can't make any specific recommendation how to override the implicit conversion, and avoid the error, without the datatype of 1) the target column, and 2) the datatype of the column returned by the SELECT, and the 3) value that is in error (is it really`'xxx'`?) Also, since I'm not seeing a question, I'm going to assume the question is "What's the reason for the observed behavior?"  The reason for that is an implicit data conversion on some "incorrect" value.

Comment: @spencer7593 1) The datatype of the target column is VARCHAR(255), 2) the same as #1, 3) the value being sent is also a VARCHAR and contains only string of characters, there are no numeric values. Annoyingly, this error only occurs on certain db's and not others where the datatypes are also all the exact same and the values are all just VARCHAR's too.

Comment: It's possible that the view query (the SELECT in the view definition) is causing an execution plan that performs an implicit datatype conversion. As previous research already revealed, the 1292 message can be handled either an *error* or as a  *warning*, depending on the statement (SELECT vs INSERT) and depending on the setting of sql_mode (STRICT, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

After investigating and checking column types within all tables involved, there was another join going on as my stored proc looped through each of the dbs. Within that loop, it called a view on each db and there was an incorrect join going on which was indeed trying to join an INT column to a VARCHAR one.

Nightmare to find but it really pays to break everything down and run through step by step.